# HttpPost method test will not run: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void doPost() from the type MyOriginalClass

Tags: unit-test, error, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a test like below.
and the error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void doPost() from the type MyOriginalClass
In MyOriginalClass, the method has parameter like doPost(String url) and this method should be giving meback a tag.

How can I resolve this error? Please help me.

```
@isTest
public class MyOriginalClassTest {
    @isTest (SeeAllData = true)static void test1(){
       
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        
        request.requestURI = 'https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/xxx';
        request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"url":"https://xxx/api.html"}');
        request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');       
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response = response;

        MyOriginalClass.doPost();
        
        System.assertNotEquals(NULL, response);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: There are _very_ few circumstances in which you should write test classes with `seeAllData=true`. Your tests should create their own data. Additionally, your assertion is a tautology because you initialize `response` to a non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

Your class Method has a definition that has a Parameter of string type as shown below

```
 doPost(String url)
```

This means you will need to pass the URL when you invoke the method.

Change your apex test class as below

```
@isTest
public class MyOriginalClassTest {
 @isTest static void test1(){
   
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
    
    request.requestURI = 'https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/xxx';
    request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"url":"https://xxx/api.html"}');
    request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');       
    request.httpMethod = 'POST';
    RestContext.request = request;
    RestContext.response = response;

    MyOriginalClass.doPost('https://example.com'); // Make sure you pass the url
    System.assertNotEquals(NULL, response);
    
   }

 }
```

As mentioned in comment do not use seeAllData and also add better assertions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mohith!!
You saved my day!!